# How to intercept request using burp on Blackberry emulator 9800

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to intercept Blackberry emulator(9800) request using Burp proxy.I am not behind the proxy.I have installed Blackberry Email and MDS service  simulator 4.1.2 and Blackberry emulator 9800. I am able to browse the internet on emulator. But, i want to intercept request using Burp. Can you let me know how to intercept request using burp through Blackberry emulator.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Burp proxy appears to listen on `127.0.0.1:8080`, [according to the Burp docs](http://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy.html).  So, run it on the same machine as your BlackBerry simulator and MDS-CS.

Here is [the BlackBerry docs for setting up a proxy in the MDS simulator](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Configure-the-BlackBerry-MDS-Simulator-to-work-behind-a-proxy/ta-p/446115).

It appears that this works for HTTP (but not HTTPS), which is typically not something you're trying to intercept, because it's encrypted anyway.